# rootFolder.WelcomePage will not accept a aspx page in same site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have been using a web template, based on STS#0, to programmatically create root site collections. There are now 10,000+ of these created over the years, and I have to update the default.aspx page.

I intend to do this a feature activated event receiver as follows:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)


         {
            SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                SPFolder rootFolder = web.RootFolder;
                rootFolder.WelcomePage = "/SitePages/TestHomePage.aspx";
                rootFolder.Update();
            }
         }
```

So each time a user opens a site collection, I can check if this feature has been activated, and then activate if necessary, using Farm properties to store the ID of feature (it is a full trust solution).

I have the new TestHomePage.aspx stored in a SitePages library that is part of each site collection, but each time the feature is activated, I just get the error:

> "Application error when access /_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx,
>   Error=The WelcomePage property must be a path that is relative to the
>   folder, and the path cannot contain two consecutive periods (..).

I have tried the following paths:

`SitePages/TestHomePage.aspx`
`/SitePages/TestHomePage.aspx`

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: PS I have also tried: Also tried:


rootFolder.WelcomePage = "/Site Pages/TestHomePage.aspx";

and 

rootFolder.WelcomePage = "Site Pages/TestHomePage.aspx";

Answer (score 1):

"/SitePages/TestHomePage.aspx" will not work. You need to remove use "SitePages/TestHomePage.aspx". The below code should work

```
        SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
        using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
        {
            SPFolder rootFolder = web.RootFolder;
            rootFolder.WelcomePage = "SitePages/Home.aspx";
            rootFolder.Update();
        }
```

Comment: I  had done too much work on one site collection - I deleted the site collection, re-created it and then:

rootFolder.WelcomePage = "Site Pages/TestHomePage.aspx"; 

worked OK.